# Flask validation failing due to presence of CSRF token

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

am using flask in my python application. I am having a strange issue from the past 2 days and I didn't do any change in my code. My login is redirecting me back to my login page itself as the function **form.validate_on_submit()** is returning false. When I debugged I found that the below function is giving success as false. This function is present in *wtforms/form.py*

```
def validate(self, extra_validators=None):
    """
    Validates the form by calling `validate` on each field.

    :param extra_validators:
        If provided, is a dict mapping field names to a sequence of
        callables which will be passed as extra validators to the field's
        `validate` method.

    Returns `True` if no errors occur.
    """
    self._errors = None
    success = True
    for name, field in iteritems(self._fields):
        if extra_validators is not None and name in extra_validators:
            extra = extra_validators[name]
        else:
            extra = tuple()
        if not field.validate(self, extra):
            success = False
    return success
```

This is what my forms.py class looks like

```
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, PasswordField, validators, ValidationError, HiddenField
from flask_wtf import Form

class RedirectForm(Form):
    ref = HiddenField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if not self.ref.data:
            self.ref.data = get_redirect_target() or ''

    def redirect(self, endpoint='index', **values):
        if is_safe_url(self.ref.data):
            return redirect(self.ref.data)
        target = get_redirect_target()
        return redirect(target or url_for(endpoint, **values))

class LoginForm(RedirectForm):
    email = StringField('Email', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.Email('Invalid Email Address')
    ])

    password = PasswordField('Password', [
        validators.DataRequired()
    ])

    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=self.email.data.lower()).first()
        if user and user.check_password(self.password.data):
            self.user = user
            return True
        else:
            self.email.errors.append("Invalid e-mail or password")

        return False

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user
```

Am using Flask-WTF version 0.10.3 and WTForms version 2.0.1. If I comment out the Form.validate(self) function in forms.py class, it works but I will be risking my site security. What should be the problem here ? No clue.

Comment: What is `RedirectForm`? May be worth putting that code there also.

Comment: @JoeDoherty question edited to include the RedirectForm class

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue till I found out I needed to render the csrf token in the template containing the form (rendered as a hidden field) so that the client could send it back to the server along with the form data to validate it

```
<form action="/user" method="POST">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{% if form.csrf_token.errors %}
    <div class="warning">You have submitted an invalid CSRF token</div>
{% endif %}
<div>{{ form.name }} {{ form.name.label }}</div>
<div>{{ form.age }}{{ form.age.label }}</div>
```